# What is the best way to manipulate web content as NSString using Swift?

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsstring

I'm trying to manipulate a block of HTML to get the strings that come after a certain substring ("bookmark">). I turned the HTML content into an `NSString` and have been using `componentsSeparatedByString("\"bookmark\">")` to make separate arrays, but then I have to go into each array and do it again to separate each occurrence. It's a bit tedious (plus I'm not sure I'm getting all the occurrences this way). Is there something more direct? Or is there a method that can count how many times the substring is used so I can come up with some sort of loop to be run that amount of times? Please provide answer as Swift-friendly as possible.

Below is a simplified example, I would like to manipulate the string in such a way that I get rid of "dont" and "want" to end up with "This is what I need"

Here is part of it. I want to be able to manipulate it in such a way as to draw out the titles of the movies (BROOKLYN and THE DANISH GIRL)-

```
> <li id="post-662129" class="post-662129 movie type-movie
> status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry tag-brooklyn
> tag-domhnall-gleeson tag-emory-cohen tag-jim-broadbent
> tag-john-crowley tag-julie-walters tag-nick-hornby tag-saoirse-ronan"
> style='margin-right: 0%;'>
>         <h2><a href="http://www.nitehawkcinema.com/movie/brooklyn/" title="Permalink to BROOKLYN" rel="bookmark">BROOKLYN</a></h2>
>         <div class="first-col">
>                       <a href="http://www.nitehawkcinema.com/movie/brooklyn/" class="poster-image-small"><img
> src="/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/poster-43c98278-5831-45e4-9eb0-304617abca97.jpg&w=120&h=177&zc=1""
> alt="Poster" /></a>                                       
>             <h3>Today's Showtimes</h3>
>             <ul class="showtimes">
>             <li><a href="#" class="check-availability" rel="666629">9:35pm</a></li>      </ul>        </div>
>         <div class="second-col">
>             <ul class="meta">
>                 <li><b>Rating:</b> PG13</li><li><b>Run Time:</b> 122 minutes</li><li><b>Director:</b> John Crowley</li><li><b>Format:</b>
> DCP</li><li><b>Language:</b> English</li><li><b>Age Policy:</b> 13 and
> Up with Guardian</li><li><b>Note:</b> OPENS AT NITEHAWK ON FRIDAY,
> JANUARY 22</li>            </ul>
>             <div class="content">
>                 <p>BROOKLYN tells the profoundly moving story of Eilis Lacey (Saoirse Ronan), a young Irish immigrant navigating her way
> through 1950s Brooklyn. Lured by the promise of America, Eilis departs
> Ireland and the comfort of her mother’s home for the shores of New
> York City. The &hellip; <a
> href="http://www.nitehawkcinema.com/movie/brooklyn/">More&nbsp;Info</a></p>
>             </div>        </div>
>         <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
> 
>     </li>
>               <div class="clear clear-divide">&nbsp;</div>
>                 
>       <li id="post-666679" class="post-666679 movie type-movie status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry tag-alicia-vikander
> tag-amber-heard tag-ben-whishaw tag-eddie-redmayne tag-the-danish-girl
> tag-tom-hooper" >
>         <h2><a href="http://www.nitehawkcinema.com/movie/the-danish-girl/"
> title="Permalink to THE DANISH GIRL" rel="bookmark">THE DANISH
> GIRL</a></h2>
>         <div class="first-col">
>                       <a href="http://www.nitehawkcinema.com/movie/the-danish-girl/"
> class="poster-image-small"><img
> src="/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/MV5BMjA0NjA4NjE2Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzIxNTY2NjE@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg&w=120&h=177&zc=1""
> alt="Poster" /></a>                                       
>             <h3>Today's Showtimes</h3>
>             <ul class="showtimes">
>             <li><a href="#" class="check-availability" rel="666687">9:50pm</a></li>      </ul>        </div>
>         <div class="second-col">
>             <ul class="meta">
>                 <li><b>Rating:</b> R</li><li><b>Run Time:</b> 120 minutes</li><li><b>Director:</b> Tom Hooper</li><li><b>Format:</b>
> DCP</li><li><b>Language:</b> English</li><li><b>Age Policy:</b> 18 and
> Up</li>            </ul>
>             <div class="content">
>                 <p>With support from his loving wife Gerda, artist Einar Wegener prepares to undergo one of the first sex-change
> operations. The remarkable love story inspired by the lives of artists
> Lili Elbe and Gerda Wegener (portrayed by Academy Award winner Eddie
> Redmayne (The Theory of Everything) &hellip; <a
> href="http://www.nitehawkcinema.com/movie/the-danish-girl/">More&nbsp;Info</a></p>
>             </div>        </div>
>         <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the string you are trying to parse?

Comment: just edited the question and added a simplified example of the type of manipulation I'm referring to.

Comment: Can you just post the raw HTML?

Comment: just added some of the HTML for reference.